# Controlling music player from web

Tags: ubuntu, music, htpc, remote-control, remote-access

I have a ubuntu machine that is connected to my house's sound system. Is there a way I can control what it is playing remotely? I have SSH access if necessary.

I typically use Rhythmbox to play music.

Comment: Have you considered a X-Windows Terminal export from the Ubuntu to your local machine? You will need a X-Server on your local machine (not as tough as it sounds) and some setup on the Ubuntu to export-X. It will give you a view of the Ubuntu desktop directly with all the controls. This has been done since before Microsoft Windows ':-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two ideas:

(1) Use turn on remote desktop on the Ubuntu box to be accessed by computers elsewhere in the house via a VNC client.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/

(2) Run Xbox Media Center (XBMC) on the Ubuntu box and operate with a remote on your iPhone, Android, or PC:
http://lifehacker.com/5501010/enhance-your-xbmc-experience-with-remote-controls-for-any-device

Answer (score 4):

[MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki)

[Web clients for MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients#Web_Clients)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like rhythmbox has a command line client called `rhythmbox-client`

You can obviously find a command list in the man pages, and a quick Google yielded this page:
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-436392.html

Also, if you're willing to give up Rhythmbox, VLC can create a web interface easily. There is documentation [on the VLC website](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/http_intf).

Comment: I can't get rhythmbox-client to work, it complains about dbus

Answer (score 1):

At my previous employer I set up a web jukebox using [RoomJuice](http://grecni.com/roomjuice/), it's quite simple and easy to use.